# lookup JSON data, return expiration date to web page

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I want to enter a club member's name, press tab and look up the "Expires" value in the "MEMBERS.JSON" file and paste it into the name="exp" field.  I have names and id numbers for both fields. How can I accomplish this?

I have a membership list stored as:

```
<script src="assets/MEMBERS.JSON"></script>
```

Sample:

```
var members = [
    {"Name": "Smith, Sally", "Expires": "2017.10.05"},
    {"Name": "Jones, Jim", "Expires": "2018.01.12"},
    {"Name": "Williams, Tony", "Expires": "2017.08.30"}
];
```

HTML:

```
<div id = "skyfall">

    <label>NAME:</label>    
    <input type = "text" name = "name" id = "P01" />

    <label>EXPIRATION DATE:</label>    
    <input type = "text" name = "exp" id = "X01" />

    <label>NAME:</label>    
    <input type = "text" name = "name" id = "P02" />

    <label>EXPIRATION DATE:</label>    
    <input type = "text" name = "exp" id = "X02" />
```

Comment: What have you tried, it's not really clear what your goal is...

Comment: Pressing tab means the browser calls the current input's `onblur` handler. Assign a function to that which gets the value and grabs the array element. This is all really basic stuff, and you're expected to do research and try to do this on your own before posting a question.

Comment: Goal is to look up in MEMBERS.JSON the key is member.Name = <input name=name" and paste the "Expires date to the EXPIRATION.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks simple to me. Please find the plunker for this:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <script data-require="jquery@*" data-semver="3.1.1" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
  <script src="script.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <h1>Hello Plunker!</h1>
  <div id="skyfall">

    <label>NAME:</label>
    <input type="text" name="name" id="P01" />

    <label>EXPIRATION DATE:</label>
    <input type="text" name="exp" id="X01" />

    <label>NAME:</label>
    <input type="text" name="name" id="P02" />

    <label>EXPIRATION DATE:</label>
    <input type="text" name="exp" id="X02" />

  </div>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    var members = [{
      "Name": "Smith, Sally",
      "Expires": "2017.10.05"
    }, {
      "Name": "Jones, Jim",
      "Expires": "2018.01.12"
    }, {
      "Name": "Williams, Tony",
      "Expires": "2017.08.30"
    }];
    
    $("#P01").on("blur", function(){
      $("#X01").val(getExpireDate($(this).val()));
    })
    
    
    function getExpireDate(name) {
    var i = null;
    for (i = 0; members.length > i; i++) {
        if (members[i].Name === name) {
            return members[i].Expires;
        }
    }
     
    return false;
};
  </script>

</body>

</html>
```

Note: I have created it in a easy to understandable manner and the ids are hard-coded. You should make it generic for your task.

Please type the name in the first textbox and hit tab it should return the expire date to you.

Comment: It looks simple and I was able to use your code effectively.

Answer (score 1):

So i put a keydown event on the textbox that checks wether tab is pressed. If tab is pressed, it searches the JSON array for the correct expiration date.

```js
var members = [
    {"Name": "Smith, Sally", "Expires": "2017.10.05"},
    {"Name": "Jones, Jim", "Expires": "2018.01.12"},
    {"Name": "Williams, Tony", "Expires": "2017.08.30"}
];

$("#P01").on('keydown', function(e) { 
  var keyCode = e.keyCode || e.which; 
  if (keyCode == 9) { 
    e.preventDefault(); 
    $.each(members, function(i, obj) {
      if(obj.Name === $('#P01').val()){
        $('#X01').val(obj.Expires);
      }
    });
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label>NAME:</label>    
<input type = "text" name = "name" id = "P01" />

<label>EXPIRATION DATE:</label>    
<input type = "text" name = "exp" id = "X01" />
```

Comment: This answer just displays the same expiration date regardless of what name you put in.